# Did visual studio add namespace to resource file?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Years ago, I use resource file to support internationalization. When a resource file was added. A namespace corresponding to the file name is generated. Then, you can access it from the code. For example, if you have a "Resources.resx" and have a string named CompanyName. You can use it as the following code:

```
lblCompany.Text = Resources.CompayName;
```

When I want to take this advantage today, I found the namespace did not added as before. Is this feature removed from Visual Studio 2008?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I know what's wrong with that. Visual studio add designer.cs behind the resource file, providing the class to handle those resource. This is only avaliable when you add resource file from solution explorer. Add resource file form File>Add... doesn't work.